# Django on Nginx serving static files but not media files when debug is False

Tags: django, nginx

My django app was running properly in production with debug set to True, when i turned it off, the app is not serving media files (uploaded by users) anymore, but the static files are served properly.

here is my settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads', 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/media/'
DOCUMENTS_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads', 'media', 'documents')
```

here are my base urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
              path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
              path('auth/', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
              path('traveller/', include('travellers.urls')),
              path('service/', include('drivers.urls')),
              path('admin/', include("management.urls")),
              path('events/', include('events.urls')),
          ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

here is my Nginx site configuration:

```
upstream app_server{
server unix:/home/envs/bus_env/run/bus.sock fail_timeout=10;
}
server {
listen 80;

# add here the ip address of your server
# or a domain pointing to that ip (like example.com or www.example.com)
server_name ***.***.***.***;

keepalive_timeout 20;
client_max_body_size 4G;

access_log /home/envs/bus_env/logs/nginx-access.log;
error_log /home/envs/bus_env/logs/nginx-error.log;

location /static/ {
    alias /home/envs/bus_env/static/;
}

location /media/ {
    # media files, uploaded by users
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/envs/bus_env/backend/uploads/media/;
}


location / {
    try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
}

location @proxy_to_app {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass http://app_server;
}
}
```

here is the nginx access log for when requesting a profile picture for example:

```
"GET /uploads/media/staff/profile_pictures/viber_image_V2JdnkG.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 799
```

this is my uploads folder hierarchy:

```
.
└── media
    ├── documents
    │   ├── drivers
    │   └── staff
    │       ├── 10
    │       ├── 11
    │       ├── 12
    │       ├── 14
    │       ├── 15
    │       ├── 16
    │       ├── 17
    │       ├── 18
    │       ├── 19
    │       ├── 20
    │       ├── 21
    │       ├── 4
    │       ├── 5
    │       ├── 8
    │       ├── 9
    │       ├── amine
    │       ├── hello
    │       ├── sdfsdg
    │       └── wassim
    ├── drivers
    │   └── profile_pictures
    ├── staff
    │   └── profile_pictures
    └── travellers
        └── profile_pictures
```

i have tried so many things, and seen so many threads, like settings the media root variable manually, changing alias to root, removing auto index...
nothing seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your media configuration as below on nginx

```
location /uploads/media/ {
    # media files, uploaded by users
    autoindex on;
    alias /home/envs/bus_env/backend/uploads/media/;
}
```